# Sort a pair of columns in an order determined by a third

Tags: excel-formula

I have text in column C with the desired order. Column A has the same values of column C but in random order. I want to sort column A with its corresponding values in column B to be in the same order as column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom list, consisting of Column C, and then do a Custom Sort.

To create the Custom list, press the Office button/ Excel Options / Popular / 
Edit custom list

[image]

Then Select and Import the relevant part of Colum C

[image]

Then select the data in Columns A:B; sort by Column A; and select the Custom list for sorting.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, It is working!!!!